# Sudden noise from laptop fan

Tags: laptop, fan

I have a MSI GP60 2QF Leopard Pro Laptop, which I have been using for just over two years (since July). Since Sunday, I noticed that my computer fan suddenly made a large noise from the fan, and the computer started to heat. So, I switched off my computer. From that day onwards, I notice that two to three times a day, the laptop will give this weird noise, and the laptop will heat up at this point. What should I do with regard to this?

Comment: Check the temp (use software) to make sure nothing is over heating. Make sure the fan is running. Ensure it's free of dust

Answer (score 3):

You description suggests that something has interfered with the fan and it's no longer working properly.

First clean the dust out of your computer and then check to make sure the fan is running properly. If it is defective it will need to be replaced.